# using connect android app to asp.net membership DB

Tags: java, android, sql-server

we have asp.net application & we want to make android app but be went to use our database asp.net membership to connect to android app do anyone now how to connect to sql-server

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question: [Membership system for web and mobile][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440107/membership-system-for-website-and-mobile-apps/12440309#12440309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is by Creating a WebService on the server where SQL-Server is running and ask the service to validate if the specified username and password are there. and maybe send the Roles that are available for this particular user.

This is maybe a good [tutorial](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/13166-connect-android-ms-sql-server-tutorial.html) about how to start doing this.